# Let's clean up the GRUB tags

Tags: discussion, tags

The GRUB tags are a mess. We have "grub" and "grub2" which *might* be fine except that the "grub" tag wiki says that it's "a modern bootloader installed by many distros nowadays". Either that's new and it should be a synonym of the "grub2" tag or it's really old, because GRUB 1 certainly isn't modern.

I propose that we blacklist "grub" and start using "grub2" and "grub-legacy". Note that both of the two alternatives will show up as suggestions when an asker types "grub".

Comment: So I killed the low hanging fruit on this. (questions tagged grub and grub2, and the tag wikis) second branch: questions tagged grub containing the word grub-legacy.

Comment: can we have a moderator lock the grub tag like the install tag? or do you think I'll finish first?

Comment: @hildred ask a new Meta question

Comment: New question posted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I support this proposal. The two versions of grub share a name but are configured and managed in ways that make answers or suggestions meant for one innapropriate for the other. Additionally, grub2 has enough new features that it will function in installations that either grub won't (EFI) or is difficult (/ on lvm,raid).

Getting rid of [grub](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grub) in favor of [grub-legacy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grub-legacy) and [grub2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grub2) is a good idea.

Comment: I'll accept this answer in a day or two but I think the silence so far means people are OK with it

Comment: Man, I clicked those "tags" like 3-5 times.