# Request for moderator assistance: tag lock

Tags: support, retagging, blacklist-request

To help push along a tag cleanup as mentioned in
[Let's clean up the GRUB tags](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2580/lets-clean-up-the-grub-tags?noredirect=1#comment2431_2580), I do hereby ask that the grub tag be locked to disallow future questions from being tagged such, in much the same fashion as the install tag.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek is there a reason this never got done? it'd be nice to have this blacklisted.